# Which 'Linux-Only' filesystem is suitable for backup and resilience in 2023

Tags: filesystems, backup, storage

I want to understand which filesystem (FS) will be most suitable for the purpose of data archival. Following are the usage parameters and requirements the FS should be able to meet:

- Backup medium is portable magnetic hard disk drive (HDD). SDD is unlikely to be used ever.
- HDD capacity is currently 5TB. Future upto 24TB.
- The HDD is rarely connected (once ~3 months), all backup archives/files are written to the disk, then safely ejected. Data reads off HDD are even rare.
- Individual file size can sometimes reach up to 100Gb. Usual size is about 5Gb.
- A **single FS partition** is desirable. Having multiple partitions is avoided unless it assists in data preservation.
- FS must be **fully supported on Linux**. Open Source FS would be a plus.
- Support for windows and mac is **not required**, however, HDD might occasionally be connected to a Linux virtual machines running on windows or mac hosts.
- The FS will be on top of a **LUKS container**. Should behave well on LUKS.
- Should be **least prone** to data corruption at rest / **bit rot** / long term cold storage.
- Should have reasonable open source data recovery tools supporting the FS - to at least recover the most recently/accidentally deleted files.
- Should have seemless data integrity checks / resilience behind the scenes.
- Unexpected HDD disconnection or power failure during writing is likely never going to happen.
- `rsync` might be occasionally used to write backup files from source.
- slow read/write speeds are permissible.

Comment: Does the filesystem, natively, have to do the "integrity" checks?  It's pretty easy to write code that'll do that on any filesytem (one process to checksum files without a checksum, another process to verify checksums).

Comment: native integrity checks is not a hard requirement, however, due to infrequent nature of accessing data, and sensitive nature of data; it should ensure data doesn't get damaged. external integrity solutions are welcome.

Comment: I'll say that long-term archival on a single disk of course has a single-point-of-failure problem. You don't happen to have two disks?

Comment: @MarcusMüller This question is about requirement from the filesystem. Of course one backup is zero, I understand. Question is more about the right filesystem than a backup strategy.

Comment: Instead of an external USB drive, have you considered buying or building a NAS and doing your backups over your local network rather than USB?   pre-built NASes are very expensive, but building your own can be cheap. There are lots of old PCs available for very little money (even free) that are more than capable of being an NFS or Samba server or `zfs send | ssh` target, and all you need to buy new is one or more drives, and maybe convenience accessories like hot-swap bays for the drives. I suggest starting with two drives (mirrored pair or RAID-1) and add more if/when you need them.

Answer (score 2):

> Should have seemless data integrity checks / resilience behind the scenes.

This would restrict the choice to

1. `dm-integrity` as device mapper layer on top of LUKS, and on top of that, any mature file system (e.g., XFS, ext4) **or**
2. ZFS or BTRFS with data checksums to detect errors on top of LUKS. Between these two, I'd say ZFS is the older/more mature, thus the preferred choice. But it's not GPL-compatible (still open source), so it's not part of the Linux kernel.

However, neither 1. nor 2. supports error *correction*, for reasons I'm not convinced about. They support error *detection*.

If you need error correction, you need add redundant data. Usually, **you'd do that with an independent second disk** (makes sense: while bit errors are bad, it's not the most unlikely scenario that if things go wrong, you have a complete hard drive not working, and then you got bigger problems than 1 file with an error).

You can, however, of course abuse your Linux system's ability to have multiple block devices on one:

1. Have a LUKS-encrypted external drive
2. In that LUKS volume, have an LVM physical volume (`pvcreate /dev/mapper/bhavesh'sopenluksvolume`)
3. In that LVM PV, you create a LVM volume group (`vgcreate externalvg /dev/mapper/bhavesh'sopenluksvolume`)
4. In that LVM VG, you create 3 LVM logical volumes (`lvcreate -n first -l 33%VG externalvg ; lvcreate -n second -l 33%VG externalvg ; lvcreate -n third -l 33%VG externalvg`)
5. Out of these three LVM LVs, you build one ZFS Zpool with RAIDZ1 (`zpool create zpool raidz1 /dev/mapper/externalvg-{first,second,third}`)

Note that mathematically, *correcting errors requires space for error-correction redundancy data*. You cannot circumvent this! In this case, that amounts to only 66% of your storage capacity being available for files.

Now you have a ZFS file system that is self-healing: If any data or metadata has been corrupted in one place, the error is corrected without your help from the redundancy.

You get quite good resilience against bit / sector errors that way. However, note that I'll say the weakest link becomes your single external disk: if that hardware fails, you lose 100% of your data.

A better resilience strategy hence would be connecting two external disks at once and using mirroring. In that case, you could just set up a Zpool containing the two LUKS volumes and a Zmirror setup – it'd be faster as well as more resilient.

If you're planning to buy two disks anyways, this is what I'd go for.

Comment: Thanks for a swift reply Marcus. Multiple disks is of course part of my strategy, however, here i am just trying to deal with single disk, FS on LUKS, and all other disks will be exact replicas.
1.) Between ZFS and time tested ext4 what are the factors that makes ZFS better?
2.) if I create Zpool, then do I have to have all the disks connected together at the same time? or they may also be used independently and later synced? say in situations like, temporarily have physical access to only one disk?
3.) Is it good idea to use without LVM? Pooling disks together is not part of strategy.

Comment: 1) see my answer. Zfs has data checksums, and a recovery mechanism. Ext4 has neither. 2) see my answer. The three volumes described are on the same disk. If you're going for the two physical disks approach, only connecting both simultaneously would allow for recovery in case of bit errors. 3) no. See my answer.

Comment: Has Oracle opened ZFS? https://www.phoronix.com/news/Linus-Says-No-To-ZFS-Linux

Comment: @oldfred well, no. But Torvalds not being able to merge GPL-incompatible code is no surprise, still. And him not seeing any value when this exact scenario (file system actually doing the integrity work instead of none at all like ext4 or no way to recover when you detect an error like btrfs) would suggest I disagree with his assessment on the amount of value that ZFS adds.

Comment: RE: your statement about ZFS "But it's not open source" - this is entirely wrong.  ZFS is open source with a copyleft license, the [CDDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Development_and_Distribution_License). It just happens to be incompatible with the GPL. This means that, unless the license is changed (very unlikely), it will never become part of the mainstream linux kernel. In practical terms, this isn't a big deal - almost all distros have DKMS packages for ZFS (so installing it is trivially easy) and some (e.g. ubuntu) ignore/dispute the licensing issue and distribute binary modules.

Comment: I looked around on ZFS. Seems like it's not very beneficial if we are considering only a single disk. Of course I can see it shines with all the advantages when we have multiple disk. However, because of the portable nature of drives, it's a little more important to have them independent - What other FS would be more suitable for a single disk scenario? Disk mirroring done with asynchronously with some other strategy is acceptable.

Comment: BTW, re: redundant data for error *correction*: both zfs and btrfs have options to store multiple copies of data (e.g. zfs has a `copies=` dataset property, defaults to 1 but can be set to 2 or 3).  Extra copies on the same disk won't help in the case of a total disk failure - for that you need at least two drives.   BTW, ZFS also has native encryption - you can run it on LUKS or you can use ZFS' own encryption (but note that this limits the `copies=` property to a maximum of 2 because it stores some of the encryption *metadata* in the same place that would be used by the third copy)

Comment: @BhaveshDiwan ZFS works fine on single drives, at least as well as any other linux filesystem. The only thing you miss out on are the benefits of having multiple drives (e.g. mirroring and raid-z), all other ZFS features (compression, error detection, even error correction if you have copies set to 2 or 3, snapshots, tunable dataset blocksizes, zvols, etc) work as well as they would with multiple drives. BTW, one advantage of zfs and btrfs is that you can snapshot the target immediately after the rsync backup finishes. And if the source is also zfs you can use zfs send (much faster than rsync)

Comment: @cas ouch, yeah I write in my comment it's not GPL compatible but miswrote in my answer that it's not Open Source. Sorry! Fixed that.

Comment: @cas never tried how much faster zfs send is, as I was disappointed with `xfsdump`'s performance and probably just never bothered to

Comment: zfs send is **much** faster than rsync.  rsync has to check at least the timestamps of every file & directory being backed up (and maybe the file checksums too), and this is very time consuming.  zfs send just sends the new/modified data & metadata because a snapshot is just a list of blocks in use at a point in time, so zfs send doesn't need to examine any files (the changed data is the difference in block lists between one snapshot and another).  When I first switched from rsync backups to zfs send, it reduced the incremental backup time from several hours to a few minutes.